# How to get call status from Twilio

Tags: php, twilio

Needs to know call status from Twilio once the call is answered or reject

```
$from ='99xyzzzz';
$to='44nnnnnn';
$response=$client->account->calls->create($from, $to,'www.example.com/Twio.php');
echo $response->status;
```

But every time it returns **queued** if a call is answered or reject. I checked Twilio logs it shows call status is Completed. How can I get actual status of a call once the call is answered or rejected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Twilio Docs](http://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/rest/call-request) say "By default, your application does not get any notification when a call is complete, if the line is busy, or no one answers. To get notification of call status, include the "StatusCallback" parameter with your REST request."

`StatusCallback` is a URL that Twilio will hit AFTER the call has been made, and will contain details about the call.

So, setup another URL on your site to handle the incoming request, then [you can use that data](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request) to update your records. You'll get `CallDuration`, `RecordingUrl`, `RecordingSid`, and `RecordingDuration` from that.

Comment: If there is continuous calls how can we know which calls status will call back ?